# Dart package Path_provider_macos has broken classes path

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

In my flutter project structure settings, the android studio gives me this problem:

```
Library Dart Packages has broken classes paths:   $home/snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider_macos-2.0.2/lib [Fix]
```

Removing this folder and repairing the cache using `dart pub cache repair` does not help.
This package `path_provider_macos-2.0.2` does not have a `lib` folder even in their repo - https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/path_provider/path_provider_macos

Every other dart package has that essential `lib` folder. Maybe it's the package error?

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

After a quick look, it seems that using this package is not necessary. As seen in the image below. Therefore I think using path_provider itself should also work for MacOs

[image: From github]

Greetz!

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I'm using path_provider and this package is included there. But it gives the problem nonetheless.